# Which NFL teams have natural grass stadiums?

Tags: trivia, american-football, nfl, venues

What percentage of NFL teams play on natural grass at their home stadium?

How many are indoor versus outdoor fields?  Please further breakdown the percentages for indoors and outdoors fields. When listing these teams, and mention whether they play indoors, or outdoors.

If a team has already committed moving to a new stadium in the near future (e.g. the LA Rams and Chargers), indicate the future stadium's grass type as a side note.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[An article on lawnstarter.com](https://www.lawnstarter.com/blog/sports-turf/nfl-stadiums-turf-or-grass/) has compiled a list of NFL stadiums, and what type of turf they play on.

**Of the 32 professional teams, 56% (or 18 teams) play on *natural grass*.**
**Of those 18 professional teams, 6% (or 1 team) plays *indoors*.**

The 18-team stadium breakdown on natural grass is as follows:

> Kansas City Chiefs (outdoors)
>     Carolina Panthers (outdoors)
>     Washington
>   Redskins (outdoors)
>     Cleveland Browns (outdoors)
>     Miami Dolphins (outdoors)
>   Pittsburgh Steelers (outdoors)
>     Green Bay Packers (outdoors)
>     San
>   Francisco 49ers (outdoors)
>     Philadelphia Eagles (outdoors)
>     Los Angeles
>   Rams (outdoors) - LA Rams will move to an artifical turf in 2019.
>     Baltimore Ravens (outdoors)
>     Tennessee Titans (outdoors)
>                                                     Los Angeles Chargers (outdoors) - LA Chargers will move to artifical turf in 2020.
>     Tampa Bay
>   Buccaneers (outdoors)
>     Chicago Bears (outdoors)
>     Denver Broncos (outdoors)
>   Arizona Cardinals (indoors)
>     Oakland Raiders (outdoors) - The Oakland raiders will move to Las Vegas sometime around 2020 and will have Sprinturf (a brand of artificial turf).

Comment: Also Arizona Cardinals don't play indoors

Comment: For the purpose of this question, consider all stadiums with retractable roofs as indoors. So the cowboys and the Texans also play indoors

Comment: Yeah, the idea is that if you play under a roof when it's cold, raining, and snowing, then you play indoors.

Comment: Totally agree with everything, just trying to point out that your comment above says the arizona cardinals don't play indoors when they have a retractable roof at University of Pheonix Stadium. Also, I will edit my answer to fit the specifications later today!

Comment: BTW Miami Dolphins play outdoors!